# An error occurred while calculating code metrics

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, code-metrics

### Issue description

When I tried to run code metrics in Visual Studio 2013 for c# project (Analyze -> Calculate Code Metrics for Solution) I get following error:

```
"an error occurred while calculating code metrics"
```

This error occurred even for the newly created project, so it was not related with some reference issues.

### Solution

To solve this issue I've executed following command as an Administrator:

```
regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VsLangproj.olb"
```

### Conclusion

- I've verified that this issue is not occurring on newly installed VS 2013 (installer with update 4 included), which means that this could be related with updating to "update 4".

Comment: Next time, please post the solution as an answer (create answer for your question).

Comment: it happens even with vs2015 but it is not solved with that command. Anyone have any idea how to resolve it on vs2015

Comment: Same Problem with VS2015 here, seaching for solution.

Comment: I experienced a similar issue that was caused by missing references in certain projects. Consider checking that.

Answer (score 15):

The issue happened due to - few of my Visual Studio projects was referring reference, for which the source was not available, as shown in the image below:

[image]

Removing those reference enabled the Code Matrices functionalities to be working again.

Comment: I use VS 2017 Version 15.9.10 and the project's references are all correct. I also ran the "regsvr32 " command but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 10):

For users who are using vs2017 15.8 .net core, this is a bug which will be fixed in next release(Dev16).
Until then you can use vs2015 or wait for an update.

[Click here checkout, this issue on c# roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/27001)

And [pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/pull/1754) which will fix this issue.

Answer (score 7):

To solve this on Windows,

1. Open command window by clicking the Start button. In the Search box, type Command Prompt, and then, in the list of results, right-click Command Prompt and then select "Run as Administrator" from the selection menu.
2. In the command prompt window paste the following command:

   **regsvr32 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VsLangproj.olb"**
3. Hit return to run the above command, a successfully registered dialog box should be shown