# How can I measure the percentage of shared code?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin

I have a solution with 5 projects:

1. Portable Class Library
2. Android app
3. iOS app
4. Windows Phone app
5. Unit tests

How can I measure the amount of code in each project (except for the unit tests)? I tried Code Metrics in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015, but VS crashes whenever I try to calculate it.

I have both a Windows PC and a Mac and both Visual Studio and Xamarin Studio, so a solution in either of those would be fine.

Comment: I have a sample app here: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MeetupManager/tree/master/MeetupManager.Analysis

Comment: Have you tried to fix the crashing?  I found two suggestions that helped me when my Code Metrics was crashing.  I tried both of the suggestions from [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072374/an-error-occurred-while-calculating-code-metrics)  I should add that I needed to restart VS after the regedit32 fix.  Then I was able to count lines of code per project with Code Metrics, which I assume is what you mean by "amount of code."

Comment: @jozolo I used the solution provided by James Montemagno